# Basement framing around finished window

Tags: basement, windows, framing, studs, steel

I'm framing my basement using steel studs. I have this sliding window on the window well (see picture) that already has a finished framing all around and is flush with the concrete wall. How do I frame around this window to be able to attach drywall to the window frame - does the drywall screw into the white portion on the window side? I don't want to remove or redo the window.

[image: closeup]
[image: corner of window]
[image: full window]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to tell what's going on; would you add a better picture (or two)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Have added a close-up view

Comment: Well, more would be better, but let's see if you get a good answer.

Comment: Maybe step back a couple of steps for another picture to give an overall view. From the 2nd pic, it looks like you're framing right across the window.

Comment: Added a picture of the full window. Ignore any metal studs you see in the previous pictures. They are just resting there and have not been screwed in yet.

Answer (score 1):

My thought is have the stud flush with the concrete wall. Then use pine wood to create a box from the edge of the window frame to the finished drywall edge. Then put the trim on the drywall to frame it.
Creates a window box ledge for fancy stuff to sit on.